# Fetch records in three slots with PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am using PHP MySQL, And i want to fetch records in 3 slots 4 records+3 records+records = 9 records, total 9 records will be fetched. but don't know how to do that by using a single MySQL query.

```
SELECT * FROM students WHERE int_student_age = 18 LIMIT 0,4   
SELECT * FROM students WHERE int_student_age = 12 LIMIT 4,7
SELECT * FROM students WHERE int_student_age = 5 LIMIT 7,9
```

I know this above code is doesn't make any sense, I just wrote it to make you guys understand.

Comment: update your question add a proper data sample as tabular text and the expected  result  ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could combine your queries using UNION ALL

```
(SELECT * FROM tbl_subscriptions WHERE int_package_id=1 ORDER BY 
int_package_id LIMIT 4) 
UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM tbl_subscriptions WHERE int_package_id=2 ORDER BY 
int_package_id LIMIT 3)
UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM tbl_subscriptions WHERE int_package_id=3 ORDER BY 
int_package_id LIMIT 2)
```